# 一部の Android 端末で、予測変換候補表示部分に EditText が写りこむ

Tags: android

Android のソフトウェアキーボードの予測変換に関するバグについて質問です。

#### アプリの構成

画面下にエディットテキスト(EditText) をおいた、 Line や Skype のチャットのようなアプリです。

#### 再現状況について

1. EditText をタップし、ソフトウェアキーボードを表示
2. てきとうな文字を入力し、予測変換を出す
3. 確定や戻るなどで、予測変換のみ閉じる
4. 予測変換の出ていた部分に EditText の表示が移ってしまう（入力などはできない）
5. キーボードそのものを閉じると、その部分も消える

#### 再現する端末について

Nexus 系の端末や、 Xperia などで発生しています。 Galaxy シリーズなどでは、発生しないようです。

スクショを添付致します。
スクショの赤枠の部分が該当部分となります。

[image: 現象再現スクショ]

上記のバグ？について、解決方法や助言を頂けると幸いです。なにとぞ、よろしくお願い致します。

＝＝＝＝＝＝追記（2015/2/11）=＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
quesera2様
コメントありがとうございます。階層ビューアーを試してみたのですが、いまいちうまく反応せず、まだできておりません。

小出しになって申し訳ありませんが、以下に簡易的ですが、階層を追記します。

// ここにチャットの内容が入ります。
   //ここにEditTextが入ります。

頂いたコメントを参考に、試してみたことを記載します。

１．ListViewを再描画　×
２．全体のViewを再描画　×
３．ハードウェアアクセラレーターをfalseに設定　→　赤枠の部分が黒くなった。
４．予測変換が消された時にListViewを一瞬GONEに設定　赤枠部分が消えたが、画面のチラつきが酷い。

以上になります。
４の方法で消すことはできたのですが、チラ付きがひどく、納得のいく状態にはなりませんでした。

＝＝＝＝＝（追記２）＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
user3009331様

情報、ありがとうございます。
こちらでも、ParrentViewにPaddingBottomを入れてみたところ、おかしくなっている部分は消えましたが、不自然に下が空いてしまうため、やはり実用的ではないようです・・・。
キーボード表示と同時に、Paddingを設定してみましたが、二度目の予測変換表示時に、おかしくなってしまいました。
根本的な原因を突き止めないと、どうしようもなさそうですね・・・。
また一歩進めた気がします。ありがとうございます！

引き続き、解決策について、ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 再現できるミニマムなレイアウトXMLか、スクリーンショットがあれば、回答者側で問題がもっと見えるかと思います。

Comment: 事象が発生したときのビュー階層を、`Hierarchy Viewer`で確認してみるなどどうでしょうか。ユーザーのビュー階層であれば、明示的に再描画を実行すればどうにかなる気がします。また、IMEを変えて原因を絞り込むなど、試行錯誤の余地もあるかと思います。

Comment: Nexus4(AndroidOS5.0.1)で再現ではないものの似たような現象になりました。自分の場合は、予測変換のみを閉じた場合、EditTextとの余白が真っ黒になる（ソフトウェアキーボードを出した時画面が上にせり上がるが、予測変換だけ閉じても元に戻らない）という現象です。ParentViewのpaddingBottomを50dpくらい取れば大丈夫っぽいのですがそういう話ではありませんですね……VerticalViewPagerでEditTextをラップする、ソフトウェアキーボードの出し入れに応じてレイアウトの崩れを覚悟でpaddingBottom値をPGで調整する、inputtype, windowinputtypeにadjustpanなど片端から突っ込むなどしてみましたが、効果がありませんでした。長文の癖に、結局何もできなくて申し訳ありません。以上、失礼いたします。